# Livewire 3.0 redirect issue from component

Tags: php, laravel-livewire, alpine.js

I have upgrade Livewire on my web app in development. Since I have to correct  a lot since changes occurs. I can't use redirect in my scripts. On my form I just have a cancel button with wire:click attribute.
When I click on it I have a progression bar that disapeared. With the inspector I have the landing page loading but not showing (like if it was ajax behind).

I hope you can help me.

in the blade :
`<x-buttons.cancel-button label="Annuler" wire:click="cancel" />`

in the component :
`public function cancel(){ return to_route('produits.index'); }`

The official documentation don't help me. I checked the cancel function with a dd() and it worked but not the redirection. I also made some research without success on the message error :

```
livewire.esm.js:6759 Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: attr is not defined
    at cloneScriptTag (livewire.esm.js:6759:12)
    at livewire.esm.js:6724:23
    at NodeList.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at prepNewScriptTagsToRun (livewire.esm.js:6721:42)
    at swapCurrentPageWithNewHtml (livewire.esm.js:6699:7)
    at livewire.esm.js:6813:13
    at preventAlpineFromPickingUpDomChanges (livewire.esm.js:6852:7)
    at livewire.esm.js:6811:11
    at livewire.esm.js:6775:9
```

Comment: Finally got my answer... I forgot to delete some lines, I had 2 Livewires instances running. So I think the bad one was trying to redirect...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got my answer... I forgot to delete some lines, I had 2 Livewires instances running. So I think the bad one was trying to redirect...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this by simply calling a component method you want to execute in laravel

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/livewire/how-can-i-redirectgo-to-another-component-with-specific-id?page=1&replyId=901772

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).